# How do I make my program accept nothing but uppercase letters in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is a C# question. I want to make my program accept nothing but uppercase letters. I have managed to make it reject lowercase letters but I don't know how to make it reject numbers and other characters. Thank you for your help!

```
#region Question3
    /* Write an application named EnterUppercaseLetters that asks the user
     * to type an uppercase letter from the keyboard. If the character entered 
     * is an uppercase letter, display OK; if it isn't an uppercase letter, 
     * display an error message. The program continues until the user types an exclamation point.
     */
static void  EnterUppercaseLetters()
    {
        //char letter;
        bool toContinue = true;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter an uppercase letter: ");
            //string input = Console.ReadLine();
            char letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            //double number = Convert.ToDouble(input);
            //int number = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
            if (letter == '!')
            {
                toContinue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (letter == Char.ToUpper(letter))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{letter} OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } while (toContinue);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

#endregion

Comment: Check with `Char.IsLetter`?

Comment: Or probably the simplest option would be to use [`Char.IsUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=net-5.0) which should handle both checks for you in one call

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use regex for that.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[A-Z]+$");
```

This will check if your string has any character that is not a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

@Moe - what you've got is good ... but maybe you'd prefer not entering the whole line.  You can try something like this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char ch;
        
    //input character 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an UPPER CASE character, or '!' to exit: ");
    while ((ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar() != '!')
    {
       if (IsUpper(ch))
            Console.WriteLine("Input character is {0}: OK", ch);
       else 
            Console.WriteLine("Input character is {0}: ERROR!", ch);
    }
}
```

This will respond *immediately* when you enter ANY keystroke.  It will exit immediately when you type "!".  And it will print "OK" (for an upper case character) or "ERROR!" otherwise.

Relevant documentation (for our peripatetic friend  Jeppe Stig Nielsen):

- [Console.ReadKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0)
- [Char.IsUpper()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Mixes three types, `bool`, `char` and `System.ConsoleKeyInfo`?

Comment: `IsUpper` is `static`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is:

```
char.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter
```

Note that `Convert.ToChar` will throw an unhandled exception if the user types an empty string or a string with length exceeding one. You may consider checking the string length, or using `Console.ReadKey` instead of `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: I like my solution better :)  ALSO: sometimes answering questions on SO is like playing whack-a-mole: questions often get closed or deleted before I've even finished a response.  So I've gotten in the habit of answering a rough reply as QUICKLY as possible, then going back and reviewing immediately.  It's frustrating when good questions get closed before I get a chance to reply, it's even more frustrating when folks "critique" while I'm still working on the revision.